# Does infinitest for IntelliJ IDEA honor the run tests settings in Gradle?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, infinitest

I have a Gradle project that I would like to use infinitest with.  However, while all test pass using the Gradle test runner, many fail in infinitest.  Is this because infinitest uses the IntelliJ test runner to run the tests?

I expect this is the case since I get similar results when I try to run tests manually using the IntelliJ test runner.

How can I configure infinitest to use Gradle as the test runner?

Answer (score 0):

Infinitest starts a new JVM to run tests, it gets the project classpath from IntelliJ but does not know it is a Gradle project.

I don't know what the Gradle test runner does differently but it would be great if you could open an issue on the [Infinitest bug tracker](https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues) with the steps to reproduce the problem (ideally with a sample project).

In case the issue is with missing JVM options you can set them using the [infinitest.args](https://infinitest.github.io/doc/config/infinitest.args) file